# Not able to modify objects passed to lua

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, luabridge

Considering the following example of using [LuaBridge](http://vinniefalco.com/LuaBridge/Manual.html) to pass objects to a lua script:

```
class Test {
public:
    double d;
    Test(double t): d(t) {};
};
Test t1(10);

auto lua_state = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(lua_state);

luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(lua_state)
    .beginNamespace("Core")
        .beginClass<Test>("Test")
            .addConstructor<void(*)(double)>()
            .addData("d", &Test::d)
        .endClass()
        .addVariable("t1", &t1)
    .endNamespace()
;
```

Apparently the passed variable can not be modified by lua:

```
Core.t1.d = 12
print(Core.t1.d)
```

*The above code prints `10`.*

Also in C++ after processing the script the variable still holds its initial value.

```
luaL_dofile(lua_state, ".../test.lua");

std::cout << t1.d << std::endl; // 10
```

However simple scalar data types (like float) that aren't object members *can* be modified. Am I missing something?

---

**Edit:**
It is apparently modifiable if I replace `Test t1(10);` with `Test *t1 = new Test(10);` or even `Test t(10);
    Test *t1 = &t;` and *still* pass `&t1` to addVariable. I do not really understand that behavior, may someone explain? (address of address?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LuaBridge makes a copy of your argument. If you define a copy constructor yourself and put a breakpoint there, you'll jump from

```
/**
  Push T via copy construction from U.
*/
template <class U>
static inline void push (lua_State* const L, U const& u)
```

This is just a contract of passing parameters in LuaBridge. I guess, it is so, since the datum has the C++ managed lifetime, and this is a safety feature. You can rewrite your datum with a new value, and you'll get what you want:

```
Core.t1.d = 12
t2 = Core.Test(10)
t2.d=12
print(Core.t1.d)
print(t2.d)
Core.t1 = t2
print(Core.t1.d)
```

outputting

```
10
12
12
```

and your C++ - side t1 will have the d value of 12

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so that means I am not at all able to use modifying methods on objects exposed from C++ with LuaBridge?

Comment: You should probably wrap the modification of your global variable into a function. Of course you can do it, but just not like that. The simplest, but not the safest method would be `Test t1_(10); Test* t1=&t1_;`

Comment: That's what I tried and that works. However with modifying methods I mean a method like `increment` in `class Test`. Calling that method from lua had no effect on the object either.

Comment: you have static data. During the wrapped call to the method or the modifier, the object is copied, so there's no difference in modifying via a method or directly via the member wrapper. What I've been thinking, a static function modifying your static object. The pointer version without having to create the object with new does the trick anyway.